# Como mostrar um input se o radio estiver marcado?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentar mostrar um `input`, ao meu ver está tudo certo, mas não funciona.
Onde estou errando?

```js
var addoutrovalor = document.getElementById("outrovalor");

if (addoutrovalor.checked) {
    document.getElementById("mostra").style.display = "block";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("mostra").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 radiopadrao">
       <label for="outrovalor">
            <input type="radio" id="outrovalor" name="valortotal[]" value="Outro valor" >
               <span>Outro valor.</span>
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" >
  <div id="mostra" class="col-md-5" >
         <label for="quanto">Quanto?</label>
               <input type="tel" name="valortotal[]" id="quanto" class="form-control" value="R$ 0,00" onkeyup="formatarMoeda(this)" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vale ressaltar: na <div id="mostra" class="col-md-5" > adicionei o display none, mas mesmo assim não funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem dois detalhes aí: você está usando `radio` ao invés de um `checkbox` e não tem callback para a função no JavaScript. Ela será executada no carregamento da página e depois não será mais.

```js
function verificaInput() {
  var addoutrovalor = document.getElementById("outrovalor");

  if (addoutrovalor.checked) {
    document.getElementById("mostra").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mostra").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 radiopadrao">
        <label for="outrovalor">
          <input type="checkbox" id="outrovalor" name="valortotal[]" value="Outro valor" onchange="verificaInput()">
          <span>Outro valor.</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="mostra" style="display: none" class="col-md-5">
        <label for="quanto">Quanto?</label>
        <input type="tel" name="valortotal[]" id="quanto" class="form-control" value="R$ 0,00" onkeyup="formatarMoeda(this)">
      </div>
    </div>
```

No caso acima, o evento `onchange` é acionado assim que o valor do input é alterado. Assim, você coloca o callback do evento para a função `verificaInput`.

Fique atenta a diferença entre um `radio` e um `checkbox`. Radios são para selecionar uma opção entre as demais, e o checkbox é para selecionar várias informações entre as demais.

Se mesmo assim insistir em usar `radio`, o código funcionará também caso `#outrovalor` seja selecionado.

Comment: Caracaaa, muito obrigada

Comment: @GabrielaRezende considere marcar a resposta como correta se ela solucionou o seu problema :)